# Cache miss & Cache Hit

Tags: c, memory, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache

Given the following code :

```
typedef  int  array[4][4];

void transpose2(array dst, array src)
{
   int i, j;
   for ( i=0; i<4; i++) {
     for ( j=0; j<4; j++) {
         dst[i][j] = src[j][i];
     }
   }
}
```

Assumptions :

- int is 4 bytes
- `src` array starts at address `0` , `dst` starts at address `64`
- the size of the cache is `32` bytes , at the beginning the cache is empty
- there is a L1 cache working under direct mapping using write-through, write-allocate
- the size of the block is 16 bytes

I'm trying to figure out the cache miss & cache hit of `dst` and `src` .

The question - to fill in the tables of **src** and **dst** arrays , where
they're empty at the beginning : [Before the run](http://s19.postimage.org/7f2vo9myb/blank.gif)

First I'll present the solution of my professor : [After the run](http://s19.postimage.org/h111ib3hv/filled.gif)

Here is my solution , but somewhere, I'm making a mistake :

Assuming that I run `i` from `1 to 4` and not from `0 to 3`

First iteration :

```
src  dst

1,1-> 1,1

2,1-> 1,2

3,1-> 1,3

4,1-> 1,4
```

Second iteration:

```
src    dst 
1,2 ->2,1

2,2 ->2,2

3,2 ->2,3

4,2 ->2,4
```

Third iteration:

```
src    dst 
1,3 -> 3,1

2,3 -> 3,2

3,3 -> 3,3

4,3 -> 3,4
```

Fourth iteration:

```
src    dst 
1,4 -> 4,1

2,4 -> 4,2

3,4 -> 4,3

4,4 -> 4,4
```

I don't understand why are there HITS at all at the tables of `dst` ,
I know that I'm wrong , can someone please explain why are there indeed HITS in the solution above ?

Regards
Ron

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because cache is usually organised into lines, each of size *n* bytes.  When you access a particular memory address, that address along with the surrounding *n-1* bytes are read into the cache.

Comment: I still can't see why are the four HITS indeed belong to their indexes , can you please explain ?

Comment: @ron: What are you expecting?

Comment: Very simple , start at the beginning : 11 into 11 : it's a miss since the cache is empty . Now the cache has 11,12,13,14 . Next , 21 into 12 : the cache already has 12 then it's a HIT (understood!) . Cache still has only 11,12,13,14 . Next ,31 into 13 : the cache already has 13 , then it's a HIT from my understanding , but the answer says MISS. Why ?

Comment: @ron: You need to take into account the fact that it's a direct-mapped cache (that's what the question says).  So that it makes it very easy for data to be evicted.  Hint: you have two memory accesses on each iteration of the loop.

Comment: Can you please explain how to do these mappings ? I've tried but it's not working , I see that for example i=0 & j=0 -> we have : dst[0][0]=src[0][0] , so I take 16 bytes and place them in cell 0 of the cache ? how do I know which cell to put it , cell 0 or cell 1 ?

Comment: @ron: The question doesn't explicitly say, so it's probably safe to assume that the cache block is addressed using the LSBs of the memory address.

Comment: That's fine,I understand that , but still I can't see the reason for the HITS . Can you please give me a reason for them ? I would have asked my lecturer , but he's on vacation and doesn't answer any mails ...

Comment: @ron: Your understanding of the hits is already correct (your 2nd comment above).  The only extra thing you have to take into account is that sometimes, accessing `src` will evict `dst` data from the cache, causing a miss for `dst`.  I suggest figuring out which cache block is used for each `dst` and `src` access.  From that, you can work out when evictions occur.

Comment: What I need to understand is how the mapping from the index [i][j] (or [j][i]) of the arrays 'src' and 'dst' are made for the cells of the cache . I think it has something with modulo or some arithmetic manipulation of 'i' and 'j' (a formula) .... ?